# can not get hardware information in .net core desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

i want to get cpu and motherboard ( and some time hardware) id
so i use below code :

```
public class SystemKey : ISystemKey
{
    public string GetDeviceId(int Length)
    {
        var uniqueKey = GetDeviceId();
        if (uniqueKey.Length >= Length)
            return uniqueKey.Substring(0, Length);

        var key = new StringBuilder(uniqueKey);
        for (int counter = uniqueKey.Length; counter <= Length; counter++)
        {
            var i = Length - uniqueKey.Length;
            key.Append(uniqueKey[i]);
        }
        return key.ToString();
    }

    public string GetDeviceId()
    {
        string uniqueKey; 
        try
        {
            uniqueKey = GetCpuSerialNumbewr() + GetMotherBoardID();
        }
        catch
        {
            ISystemKey alternativeSystemKey = new AlternativeSystemKey();
            uniqueKey = alternativeSystemKey.GetDeviceId(); 
        }
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(uniqueKey))
        {
            throw new Exception("can not get device id for current system"); 
        }
        return uniqueKey;
    }

    private string GetCpuSerialNumbewr()
    {
        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        string query = "Select * FROM Win32_Processor";
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        foreach (ManagementObject info in searcher.Get())
        {
            results.Add(
                info.GetPropertyValue("ProcessorId").ToString());
        }

        return results.FirstOrDefault();

    }
    private string GetMotherBoardID()
    {
        string mbInfo = String.Empty;

        //Get motherboard's serial number 
        ManagementObjectSearcher mbs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_BaseBoard");
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in mbs.Get())
        {
            mbInfo += mo["SerialNumber"].ToString();
        }
        return mbInfo;
    }
}
```

and alternative system key (in above code invoked) :

```
public class AlternativeSystemKey : ISystemKey
{
    private static string identifier(string wmiClass, string wmiProperty)
    {
        string result = "";
        System.Management.ManagementClass mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass(wmiClass);
        System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
        foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            //Only get the first one
            if (result == "")
            {
                try
                {
                    result = mo[wmiProperty].ToString();
                    break;
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    private static string cpuId()
    {
        //Uses first CPU identifier available in order of preference
        //Don't get all identifiers, as it is very time consuming
        string retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "UniqueId");
        if (retVal == "") //If no UniqueID, use ProcessorID
        {
            retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "ProcessorId");
            if (retVal == "") //If no ProcessorId, use Name
            {
                retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "Name");
                if (retVal == "") //If no Name, use Manufacturer
                {
                    retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "Manufacturer");
                }
                //Add clock speed for extra security
                retVal += identifier("Win32_Processor", "MaxClockSpeed");
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
    //BIOS Identifier
    private static string biosId()
    {
        return identifier("Win32_BIOS", "Manufacturer")
        + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "SMBIOSBIOSVersion")
        + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "IdentificationCode")
        + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "SerialNumber")
        + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "ReleaseDate")
        + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "Version");
    }
    //Main physical hard drive ID
    private static string diskId()
    {
        return identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "Model")
        + identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "Manufacturer")
        + identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "Signature")
        + identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "TotalHeads");
    }
    //Motherboard ID
    private static string baseId()
    {
        return identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "Model")
        + identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "Manufacturer")
        + identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "Name")
        + identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "SerialNumber");
    }
    //Primary video controller ID
    private static string videoId()
    {
        return identifier("Win32_VideoController", "DriverVersion")
        + identifier("Win32_VideoController", "Name");
    }

    public string GetDeviceId(int length)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string GetDeviceId()
    {
        return baseId() + cpuId() + biosId();
    }
}
```

so in this two class we have some method  , but when we use them in some systems is not work(exception) and the error say  : "microsoft.net\framework\v4.030319\wminet_utils does not
have all required functions. please update the .net framework"
but the question is that : "why this exception accur ? because application written with .net core
and published as self contained , it does not means application should work without any dependency ?
summary question :

1. is there any compatible .net core code for getting hardware information ?
   2)why when application published as self contained it say's : "i need more dependency to install" ?
   3)best way for resolve above problem
   (srry for bad english)

Comment: Maybe it helps. There is a tool "open hardware monitor" which is fully written in .NET not core but adaptable. [Here is the git](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we did not find any solution but how we resolved it ?
actulay when we creating a .net framework app and try to get hardware information there is no problem (the code does not work in .net core(system.managment version4/5/6) so we created an .net framework console application just for getting hardware information and invoke that application in new proccess and reading .net framework console app new line result  , the code example :

```
protected string GetDeviceId(int length)
    {
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "WpfApp.IdGenerator.exe",
                Arguments = $"{length}",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        proc.Start();
        return proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried referencing the `System.Management` nuget package in .Net6 and it worked without issues.

In fact, looking at the package itself for version 6.0, [it has a version for .Net6 and .Net Core 3.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/6.0.0-preview.6.21352.12). Of course, you don't mention what version you referenced, but given the error you're getting you probably linked to version 5.0, [which doesn't have a .Net Core 3+ version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/5.0.0) (you also don't mention what .Net version you're trying to run this under). So it's most likely binding to the .Net Framework version, which may or may not exist on other systems.

Comment: thanx for the answer , iam using .net core 3.1 and the application published as self contained, but i dont know why application need .net framework ? is not .net core enough ?

Comment: Because you're most likely binding to a version of the nuget package that doesn't have the net core version you're targetting. Read the answer I literally just wrote.

Comment: srry my english language is so bad,  so i  understand what you said hardly , 
but you linked a nuget package and said  this is compatible with .net core 3.1 and .net 6 ? this link :
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/6.0.0-preview.6.21352.12
?
afterall it should work without issues ?

Comment: Version 6 of the package, yes. After all this time you still haven't said what version you are using.

Comment: iam refrencing version 5 of system.management and app running in .net core 3.1 , so which version should i choose ?

Comment: So I guessed right. Read my answer, please.

Comment: okey i will install version 6 of the package but  i should mention that application run an my system without problem (and many other users) but just some user have this problem

Comment: "But it works at my desk" -- I'd fire you on the spot if you told me that. You don't write software for yourself, you write it for the people who will pay to use it, and so it needs to work for them.